# Variable not available in different class

Tags: cloud, salesforce, apex-code

I have two global classes. In the CreateAndModify class i have an execute functions which has a for loop which calls a processRecord method of my other class i.e CreateAndModifyProcessor. The problem is that there is a collection of list declared in my first class which i cannot access in the second class. Is there any way to do it and is it even a good ides to do it this way ?..

```
global class CreateAndModify implements
Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{

global void execute(
Database.BatchableContext BC,

List<sObject> listObj){

list <Account__c> inAcc = new list<Account__c>();

for (sObject lo : listObj){
      processor.processRecord(lo);
}

insert inAcc; // The list object which i 
              // am modifying in the processRecord function has to be added to       
              // the database. So, is it a good idea to add/populate the            
              // in other function of other class
}


global class CreateAndModifyProcessor {
global void processRecord(sObject listObj){
Unprocessed_Agreement__c temp = (Unprocessed_Agreement__c)listObj;

Account__c tempAcc = new Account__c();

inAcc.add(tempAcc); // This line throws an error
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list, `inAcc` is defined within the execute method and so it's scope is restricted to that method and not available outside of it or the class the method belongs to. If you absolutely have to keep the structure you've laid out, then why not just pass the list of accounts as a parameter to the processing method as below?

```
global class CreateAndModify implements
    Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> listObj) {

        list <Account__c> inAcc = new list<Account__c>();

        for (sObject lo : listObj) {
            processor.processRecord(lo, inAcc);
        }

        insert inAcc;
    }
}

global class CreateAndModifyProcessor {

    global void processRecord(sObject listObj, list<Account> listAcc) {
        Unprocessed_Agreement__c temp = (Unprocessed_Agreement__c)listObj;
        Account__c tempAcc = new Account__c();
        listAcc.add(tempAcc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`list <Account__c> inAcc = new list<Account__c>();` is not a global List!

you should move it outside the execute method, do something like this

```
global class CreateAndModify implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{ 

   global  list <Account__c> inAcc = new list<Account__c>();

  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> listObj){

      for (sObject lo : listObj){
      processor.processRecord(lo);
       }

   insert inAcc; 
 }
}
```

Comment: method does not exist or incorrect signature: inAcc.add(SOBJECT:Account__c)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of restructuring the code a bit, to maybe return the account or list of accounts from processRecord and add it to inAcc in that way? It might look something like this:

```
list <Account__c> inAcc = new list<Account__c>();

for (sObject lo : listObj){
    inAcc.addAll(processor.processRecord(lo));
}

insert inAcc;

global class CreateAndModifyProcessor {
    global list<Account> processRecord(sObject listObj){
        list<Account> accs = new list<Account>();
        Unprocessed_Agreement__c temp = (Unprocessed_Agreement__c)listObj;
        ... // some code that adds records to accs
        return accs;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have three similar list functions as 
list <Account__c> inAcc = new list<Account__c>();
So, i cannot restructure as you said because then i should have three functions which return there respective objects like Account